# Sending image to server: http POST vs custom tcp protocol

Tags: python, sockets, wsgi

I am working out how to build a python app to do image processing. A client (not a web browser) sends an image and some text data to the server and the server's response is based on the received image.

One method is to use a web server + WSGI module and have clients make a HTTP POST request (using multipart/form-data). The http server then 'works out' the uploaded image and other data that the program can use.

Another method is to create a protocol that only sends the needed data and is handled within the application. The application would be doing everything (listening on the port, etc).

Is one of these a stand-out 'best' way (if yes, which one?), or is it more up to preference (or is there another way which is better)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's more up to your needs, the size of the images, and your general knowledge of network programming.

In terms of simplicity, posting an image to the webserver using WSGI would be fairly simple, and you wouldn't have to worry about handling connections, sockets, error handling due to busy network ports, etc.

Another argument in favor of this approach is that you can easily reuse this "feature" if you already have it working on a webserver, say, by including a browser client. It might not be one of your needs now, but the door is left open.

This would be my choice.

Also, in Python you have a huge plethora of web frameworks to choose from, from the likes of Django, which is probably a huge overkill for your needs, to something alot simpler, like http://flask.pocoo.org/ which might just suit your needs and is really simple to set up.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion HTTP is an ideal protocol for sending files or large data, and its very common use, easy to suit any situation. If you use a self-created protocol, you may find it hard to transform when you get other client needs, like a web API.

Maybe the discussions about HTTP's lack of instantaneity and agility make you hesitate about choosing HTTP, but that mostly something about instant messaging and server push, there are better protocols. But when it comes to stability and flexiblity, HTTP is always a good choice.